# How do I send all eth deposited to another address

Tags: ether

How to receive ether in wallet address and forward to another address immediately on successful deposit?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about a wallet, you can't attach on-chain functionality to it. It has to happen off-chain. So some off-chain service has to monitor your wallet for deposits and transfer any deposit to another address. This of course also means that the service has to have your private key in order to create transactions from the wallet.

No, I don't know which ready service you could use for this. You can probably find some online, but do your own research and decide on which service you are willing to trust with your private key.

Comment: Ok. Thanks if you ever see any service that does this please update me. Thanks a lot